# How to create horizontal swipeable menu without scrollbar?

Tags: html, css, scroll, menu, touch

I want to have a swipeable horizontal menu on my mobile website, just like Google uses on it's results page. I created one with basic html/css, which works fine but I cannot get rid of the scroll bar...

Here's the code:

```
<div style=" -ms-overflow-style: -ms-autohiding-scrollbar; -webkit-user-select: none; display: block; height: 50px; overflow-y: hidden; padding: 0px; position: relative; -webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch; overflow-x: scroll;">
          <div style="display: inline-block; position: relative; white-space: nowrap; overflow: hidden;">
               <div style="display: inline-block; height: 40px; text-align: center; padding: 0 16px;">ITEM</div>
               <div style="display: inline-block; height: 40px; text-align: center; padding: 0 16px;">ITEM</div>
               <div style="display: inline-block; height: 40px; text-align: center; padding: 0 16px;">ITEM</div>
               <div style="display: inline-block; height: 40px; text-align: center; padding: 0 16px;">ITEM</div>
               <div style="display: inline-block; height: 40px; text-align: center; padding: 0 16px;">ITEM</div>
               <div style="display: inline-block; height: 40px; text-align: center; padding: 0 16px;">ITEM</div>
               <div style="display: inline-block; height: 40px; text-align: center; padding: 0 16px;">ITEM</div>
          </div>
     </div>
```

Any idea?

[See my menu here](http://www.melicerretini.com/test)

[See Google example here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RLqMj.jpg)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can make a container `<div>` element that holds the scrolling `<div>`.
This parent `<div>` style can be set to: `oveflow:hidden` and its size smaller than its child `<div>` -of which the style is set to `overflow:scroll`.
This way the scrollbar is hidden and you need not worry about doing this with JavaScript; however:

- It is recommended that you create your CSS classes in either a `<style>` element, or a separate CSS file in which you can define these classes, and   use these classes in your HTML like: `<div class="menu">...`

Using inline CSS as per the example above renders unmanageable code, especially in larger projects

#### Update

Here's a full example:

```css
div
{
    box-sizing:border-box;
    -moz-box-sizing:border-box;
    -webkit-box-sizing:border-box;
}

.scrollHider
{
    display:inline-block;
    width:302px;
    height:162px;
    overflow:hidden;
    border:1px solid #AAA;
}

.menuBox
{
    width:315px;
    height:175px;
    overflow:scroll;
    white-space:nowrap;
}

.menuSection
{
    width:300px;
    height:160px;
    display:table-cell;
    overflow:hidden;
}

.menuItem
{
    width:300px;
    height:40px;
    text-align:center;
    padding:10px;
    border:1px solid #AAA;
}
```

```html
<div class="scrollHider">
    <div class="menuBox">
        <div class="menuSection">
            <div class="menuItem">ITEM 1</div>
            <div class="menuItem">ITEM 2</div>
            <div class="menuItem">ITEM 3</div>
            <div class="menuItem">ITEM 4</div>
        </div>
        <div class="menuSection">
            <div class="menuItem">ITEM 5</div>
            <div class="menuItem">ITEM 6</div>
            <div class="menuItem">ITEM 7</div>
            <div class="menuItem">ITEM 8</div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Preview: *(partial screenshot)*

[image: preview]

The preview (above) shows where it is scrolled to the right. Copy & paste the code above in an empty HTML file, save & open in web browser. You can also click it and use keyboard arrows to scroll if you're not using a phone/touch-screen.

Comment: That is wonderful, I'm definitely going to work from this as it seems to work as I needed! Thanks a lot :)

Answer (score 0):

First put this link in your head tags. it is from [purecss.io](http://purecss.io/) which is a small library of css modules. I use pure in about 40% of my projects.

```
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://yui.yahooapis.com/pure/0.6.0/pure-min.css">
```

Then put this into the body of your HTML page. I would recommend separating the css and js into their own files later.

```
<style>
    .custom-menu-wrapper {
        background-color: #808080;
        margin-bottom: 2.5em;
        white-space: nowrap;
        position: relative;
    }

    .custom-menu {
        display: inline-block;
        width: auto;
        vertical-align: middle;
        -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
    }

    .custom-menu .pure-menu-link,
    .custom-menu .pure-menu-heading {
        color: white;
    }

    .custom-menu .pure-menu-link:hover,
    .custom-menu .pure-menu-heading:hover {
        background-color: transparent;
    }

    .custom-menu-top {
        position: relative;
        padding-top: .5em;
        padding-bottom: .5em;
    }

    .custom-menu-brand {
        display: block;
        text-align: center;
        position: relative;
    }

    .custom-menu-toggle {
        width: 44px;
        height: 44px;
        display: block;
        position: absolute;
        top: 3px;
        right: 0;
        display: none;
    }

    .custom-menu-toggle .bar {
        background-color: white;
        display: block;
        width: 20px;
        height: 2px;
        border-radius: 100px;
        position: absolute;
        top: 22px;
        right: 12px;
        -webkit-transition: all 0.5s;
        -moz-transition: all 0.5s;
        -ms-transition: all 0.5s;
        transition: all 0.5s;
    }

    .custom-menu-toggle .bar:first-child {
        -webkit-transform: translateY(-6px);
        -moz-transform: translateY(-6px);
        -ms-transform: translateY(-6px);
        transform: translateY(-6px);
    }

    .custom-menu-toggle.x .bar {
        -webkit-transform: rotate(45deg);
        -moz-transform: rotate(45deg);
        -ms-transform: rotate(45deg);
        transform: rotate(45deg);
    }

    .custom-menu-toggle.x .bar:first-child {
        -webkit-transform: rotate(-45deg);
        -moz-transform: rotate(-45deg);
        -ms-transform: rotate(-45deg);
        transform: rotate(-45deg);
    }

    .custom-menu-screen {
        background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
        -webkit-transition: all 0.5s;
        -moz-transition: all 0.5s;
        -ms-transition: all 0.5s;
        transition: all 0.5s;
        height: 3em;
        width: 70em;
        position: absolute;
        top: 0;
        z-index: -1;
    }

    .custom-menu-tucked .custom-menu-screen {
        -webkit-transform: translateY(-44px);
        -moz-transform: translateY(-44px);
        -ms-transform: translateY(-44px);
        transform: translateY(-44px);
    }

    @media (max-width: 62em) {

        .custom-menu {
            display: block;
        }

        .custom-menu-toggle {
            display: block;
            display: none\9;
        }

        .custom-menu-bottom {
            position: absolute;
            width: 100%;
            border-top: 1px solid #eee;
            background-color: #808080\9;
            z-index: 100;
        }

        .custom-menu-bottom .pure-menu-link {
            opacity: 1;
            -webkit-transform: translateX(0);
            -moz-transform: translateX(0);
            -ms-transform: translateX(0);
            transform: translateX(0);
            -webkit-transition: all 0.5s;
            -moz-transition: all 0.5s;
            -ms-transition: all 0.5s;
            transition: all 0.5s;
        }

        .custom-menu-bottom.custom-menu-tucked .pure-menu-link {
            -webkit-transform: translateX(-140px);
            -moz-transform: translateX(-140px);
            -ms-transform: translateX(-140px);
            transform: translateX(-140px);
            opacity: 0;
            opacity: 1\9;
        }

        .pure-menu-horizontal.custom-menu-tucked {
            z-index: -1;
            top: 45px;
            position: absolute;
            overflow: hidden;
        }

    }
    </style>
    <div class="custom-menu-wrapper">
        <div class="pure-menu custom-menu custom-menu-top">
            <a href="#" class="pure-menu-heading custom-menu-brand">Brand</a>
            <a href="#" class="custom-menu-toggle" id="toggle"><s class="bar"></s><s class="bar"></s></a>
        </div>
        <div class="pure-menu pure-menu-horizontal pure-menu-scrollable custom-menu custom-menu-bottom custom-menu-tucked" id="tuckedMenu">
            <div class="custom-menu-screen"></div>
            <ul class="pure-menu-list">
                <li class="pure-menu-item"><a href="#" class="pure-menu-link">Home</a></li>
                <li class="pure-menu-item"><a href="#" class="pure-menu-link">About</a></li>
                <li class="pure-menu-item"><a href="#" class="pure-menu-link">Contact</a></li>
                <li class="pure-menu-item"><a href="#" class="pure-menu-link">Blog</a></li>
                <li class="pure-menu-item"><a href="#" class="pure-menu-link">GitHub</a></li>
                <li class="pure-menu-item"><a href="#" class="pure-menu-link">Twitter</a></li>
                <li class="pure-menu-item"><a href="#" class="pure-menu-link">Apple</a></li>
                <li class="pure-menu-item"><a href="#" class="pure-menu-link">Google</a></li>
                <li class="pure-menu-item"><a href="#" class="pure-menu-link">Wang</a></li>
                <li class="pure-menu-item"><a href="#" class="pure-menu-link">Yahoo</a></li>
                <li class="pure-menu-item"><a href="#" class="pure-menu-link">W3C</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
    <script>
    (function (window, document) {
    document.getElementById('toggle').addEventListener('click', function (e) {
        document.getElementById('tuckedMenu').classList.toggle('custom-menu-tucked');
        document.getElementById('toggle').classList.toggle('x');
    });
    })(this, this.document);
    </script>
```

Comment: Thanks for your help, unfortunatelly it didn't work :( Any other idea?

Comment: Did you try it on a mobile device after doing my edits?

Comment: Yes, I deleted the 2 overflows and tried it with my iphone

Comment: I just edited my answer. See if this works. If it does then it was a simple fix. I applied this to the original code you posted on here, just so you know.

Comment: I'm sorry, still not working... I tried another solution posted up above, and seems to work fine. Yes it's much more complex but might get it done

Comment: I am glad you found the solution. If you want I can change my answer up and show you the code to a menu that I have used if you would like. It functions as a normal menu on desktop but once it detects a smaller screen it collapses. the mobile user then can click on it to reveal the menu and it is swipeable. Interested?

Comment: Yes please, I'd be glad to see!!

Comment: Just put it in my answer.

Comment: It looks like it is not getting the link to the pure.css source. Did you put it in the head of your html document?

Comment: ok I looked at the source and you put the style in the head. Put that in the body with the rest of the code, before the other code. put the <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://yui.yahooapis.com/pure/0.6.0/pure-min.css"> in the head. Then it should work.

Comment: It did work now, it looks great! Thanks a lot pal :)

Comment: Your welcome. can you send me your test link so I can see what it looks like?

Comment: So far I just copied your code and checked functionnality but hasn't work on it yet, I'll let you know if we go ahead and use this one